# How to refer PageReference method from apex test class

Tags: unit-testing, testing, salesforce, visualforce, force.com

I am new to apex, I have created a button to call the apex class through the visual force page. 
Here is my visual force page code.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" 
extensions="myclass" 
action="{!autoRun}"> 
</apex:page>
```

Here is my apex class.

```
public class myclass {
    private final Opportunity o;
    String tmp;

   public myclass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.o = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
    }
    public PageReference autoRun() { 
        String theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

   for (Opportunity o:[select id, name, AccountId,  from Opportunity where id =:theId]) {

                 //Create the Order
                    Order odr = new Order(  
                    OpportunityId=o.id
                    ,AccountId = o.AccountId
                    ,Name = o.Name
                    ,EffectiveDate=Date.today()
                    ,Status='Draft'
                    );
                insert odr;
                tmp=odr.id;             
              }                  
        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/' + tmp);  
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
      }
}
```

I want to create test class. **I don't know how to refer PageReference autoRun() method from test class.** Guys need help if some one can tell me about test class of this apex class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to configure the StandardController for the inserted Opportunity. Then pass the StandardController to pass to the constructor before calling the method to test.

E.g.

```
public static testMethod void testAutoRun() {

    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
    // TODO: Populate required Opportunity fields here
    insert o;

    PageReference pref = Page.YourVisualforcePage;
    pref.getParameters().put('id', o.id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pref);

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(o);

    myclass mc = new myclass(sc);
    PageReference result = mc.autoRun();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, result);

}
```